# Extracting time series from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a multi-index of stock prices and I am trying to extract all closing prices for a given symbol, such as all XLI Close prices.

I have figured out how to call a year, but not multiple years or preferably all of the data - Code attached.  I am a newbie to Multi-Indexing, can anyone point out how this is done?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2ao4.jpg)

In[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2ao4.jpg) df.loc[("2021", "xli"), "close"].head() #How to call all closing data?
Out[2]
date        symbol
2021-01-04  xli       86.41
2021-01-05  xli       87.26
2021-01-06  xli       89.34
2021-01-07  xli       89.83
2021-01-08  xli       89.61
Name: close, dtype: float64

Comment: You say "code attached", but there's no code in your question. Please include the text of the code before posting instead of editing the question several times after posting - the editor has a preview, you're now editing in front of everyone.

Comment: Don't upload images of code, include the relevant code in the question and properly format it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.